# Cognos 10 - Display data from an SQL query on multiple rows in a list

Tags: report, cognos, cognos-10

I have a query that returns a) worked hours and b) non-worked hours for the same work/task to be displayed for each day of the week in different rows.

List block display should look like:

```
Header: Work/Task| Worked/Non-Worked Hours| Day 1| Day 2 ....Day7
Data row1: Work/Task | Worked Hours (just text label)| Day 1 hrs| Day 2 hrs.... Day 7 hrs
Data row2: Work/Task | Non-Worked Hours (just text label) | Day 1 hrs| Day 2 hrs.... Day 7 hrs
```

I've got the report display created as above, and the query returns the data correctly, but the problem is when there are multiple work/tasks for the same week, the list only seems to be displaying the non-worked hours for the last task returned.

For example: Let's say there are 3 tasks for the day: A,B, C

The display looks like:

```
Header: Work/Task| Worked/Non-Worked Hours| Day 1| Day 2 ....Day7
Data row1: A | Worked Hours| Day 1 hrs| Day 2 hrs.... Day 7 hrs
Data row2: B | Worked Hours| Day 1 hrs| Day 2 hrs.... Day 7 hrs
Data row3: C | Worked Hours| Day 1 hrs| Day 2 hrs.... Day 7 hrs
Data row4: C | Non-Worked Hours| Day 1 hrs| Day 2 hrs.... Day 7 hrs
```

Ideally, it should display non-worked hours for A and B too. Like I said, the query returns these values, but the list doesn't seem to display it.

Expected result:

```
Header: Work/Task| Worked/Non-Worked Hours| Day 1| Day 2 ....Day7
Data row1: A | Worked Hours| Day 1 hrs| Day 2 hrs.... Day 7 hrs
Data row2: A | Non-Worked Hours| Day 1 hrs| Day 2 hrs.... Day 7 hrs
Data row3: B | Worked Hours| Day 1 hrs| Day 2 hrs.... Day 7 hrs
Data row4: B | Non-Worked Hours| Day 1 hrs| Day 2 hrs.... Day 7 hrs
Data row5: C | Worked Hours| Day 1 hrs| Day 2 hrs.... Day 7 hrs
Data row6: C | Non-Worked Hours| Day 1 hrs| Day 2 hrs.... Day 7 hrs
```

When there is only only task involved though, the list displays both worked and non-worked hours as excepted. Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: What kind of query feeds the list? Is it a single query or is it derived from a join, union, or custom SQL object? Can you think of anything that makes Work/Task C different from the others?

Answer (score 1):

On your final query that is feeding into your list, change the Aggregate Function from 'Automatic' to 'None' for your first two columns, and set the remaining columns to have Aggregate Function of 'Total'.

It sounds like the automatic aggregation is doing a max or min.  When you are working with queries that pull from other queries in Report Studio, make sure you are using your 'Run -> View Tabular Data' on each individual query, so you know at what step the data is being lost.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips, guys. The query was built with several UNIONS. I managed to identify and rectify the issue myself. I selected the complete list and applied a GROUPING based on Non-Worked Hours. That did the trick.